# Обращение к объекту как к list

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

В PHP существуют возможность обращаться к объекту как к массиву, для этого - внутри объекта создается поле с массивом, а также реализуются методы интерфейса `ArrayAccess` через которые выполняется доступ к этому полю ([Документация с примером](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.arrayaccess.php)), после чего, к объекту можно обращаться как массиву, т.е. делать так:

```
$obj = new ObjectWithArrayAccess();
$obj[0] = 'Hello';
$obj[1] = 'world';
print(count($obj));
print($obj[0], $obj[1]);
```

Существует ли такая возможность в python3 для `list`?

UPD: Зачем это нужно: у меня есть класс `Matrix` с полем `matrix`:

```
class Matrix:
     def __init__(self):
         self.matrix = [
             [0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0],
         ]
```

Для того чтобы получить доступ к полю `matrix`, мне нужно каждый раз писать `print(matrixObject.matrix[0])` - это не удобно, хотелось бы просто написать `print(matrixObject[0])`

Comment: Зачем это нужно?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev добавил UPD с пояснением

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно.

Для этого нужно переопределить магические методы:

- [_*getitem*_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) - вызывается при обращении к оператору `[]` как getter'у
- [_*setitem*_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) - вызывается при обращении к оператору `[]` как setter'у
- [_*len*_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__)     - вызывается у объекта для метода `len`

Пример:

```
class ObjectWithArrayAccess:
    def __init__(self):
        self._fields = dict()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._fields[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._fields[key] = value

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._fields)
    
    
obj = ObjectWithArrayAccess()
print(bool(obj))       # False
obj[0] = 'Hello'
obj[1] = 'world'
print(obj._fields)     # {0: 'Hello', 1: 'world'}
print(len(obj))        # 2
print(bool(obj))       # True
print(obj[0], obj[1])  # Hello world
```